Convert Rust (Wasm-Game-Of-Life style app) to single embedded html page
I was following the guide at: https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/introduction.html
I had a lot of trouble getting it to work. Much of this had to do with the contents of the www directory not working on an ordinary web server. It needed to be served with npm run start. npm run build generated the dist directory, but it was missing index.js in addition to some harder-to-solve problems. I got it to work by running npm run start -- --port 4301 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check on my production server. (see http://dansted.org:4301/ ). Eventually I got it to work with my default webserver (see https://dansted.org/zerosum ) using How to make the Rust Game of Life WebAssembly work as a static website? and a bit of persistance.
However, what I would like to have is a simple single HTML file that I can easily run from anywhere. I found this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473757/3215004
I pasted my base64 wasm into that code, but loading the resulting HTML file into Firefox gave the following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: import object field './j_game_of_life_bg.js' is not an Object. I think this means that something is hardcoding paths to js files into my WASM.
So, is there a way to stop my WASM depending on external js files? (or otherwise embed all the required pieces into a single HTML file?)

I don't recommend embedding you .wasm files into HTML. Even if that's possible, that's a bad idea. Serve them on their own. JavaScript can be embedded, but it may also not be a good idea for large JavaScript files. Instead, try to fix your server problems.

I have fixed my server problems. However, there are issues with non-embedded WASM not working when included in downloading HTML files. I can hardly ask the world to fix their file:// implementation to support non-embedded WASM.
